# Extract 'dominant' colors from HSV model? (not from RGB model)

Tags: javascript, rgb, hsv

i'm looking for a get color pallet from image.

i could get RGB data from image

```
getRgbData() {
    this.canvas = window.document.createElement('canvas')
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.width = this.canvas.width = image.width || image.naturalWidth
    this.height = this.canvas.height = image.height || image.naturalHeight
    this.context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height)
    return this.context.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
}
```

and convert RGB values to HSV model (rgbToHsv method wrote from https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256#file-color-conversion-algorithms-js-L1)

```
getHsvData() {
    const { data, width, height } = this.getRgbData()
    const pixcel = width * height
    const q = 1
    const array = []
    for (var i = 0, r, g, b, offset; i < pixcel; i = i + q) {
        offset = i * 4
        r = data[offset + 0]
        g = data[offset + 1]
        b = data[offset + 2]
        array.push({ r, g, b })
    }

    return array.map(l => this.rgbToHsv(l.r, l.g, l.b))
}
```

it result like this (it is converted data from RGB 24bit)

```
[
   {h: 0.6862745098039215, s: 0.7727272727272727, v: 0.17254901960784313},
   {h: 0.676470588235294, s: 0.723404255319149, v: 0.1843137254901961},
   .....
]
```

[color-thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/blob/master/src/color-thief.js) and [vibrant.js](https://github.com/akfish/node-vibrant) is get dominant color from RGB model, but i want to
get dominant color from converted HSV model.
(i heard that extract color from hsv is more fit in human eyes. is it right?)

how can i extract color form HSV model..?

Comment: Have a look at [tinycolor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) -- I used it in one of my projects. Works great, easy to use.

Comment: @GreatBigBore i want to know extract dominant color from those values :(
(i think is related to color quantization)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567643/getting-dominant-colour-value-from-hsv-histogram) maybe, or [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=hsv+dominant+color&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS688US688&oq=hsv+dominant+color&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61.2919j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Your hue is your dominant color... Not sure what your asking....

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn but when converted RGB model to HSV, then lots of hue exists. right? (thousands of independent values)

Comment: Yes... Are you trying to get the dominant value of the entire image?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thats right :)

Comment: @GreatBigBore sorry not helpful for me :( it just telling how to use matlab library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing we need to do is get the average color of the image. We can do that by adding each color channel individually then dividing by the height and the width of the canvas.

```
function channelAverages(data, width, height) {
  let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0
  let totalPixels = width * height
  for (let i = 0, l = data.data.length; i < l; i += 4) {
    r += data.data[i]
    g += data.data[i + 1]
    b += data.data[i + 2]
  }
  return {
    r: Math.floor(r / totalPixels),
    g: Math.floor(g / totalPixels),
    b: Math.floor(b / totalPixels)
  }
}
```

Next we will want to convert the returned color's average to HSL, we can do that with this function (Which you also link to above).

```
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
  var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

  if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
  } else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
      case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
      case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
      case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
    }
    h /= 6;
  }
  return [h, s, l];
}
```

So, to get our output we can do this:

```
let data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
let avg = channelAverages(data, width, height)
console.log(rgbToHsl(avg.r, avg.g, avg.b))
```

If we want numbers we can use in an editor (Such as PhotoShop or Gimp) to verify our results, we just need to multiply each:

```
h = h * 360 
    Example: 0.08 * 360 = 28.8

s = s * 100 
    Example: 0.85 * 100 = 85

l = l * 100 
    Example: 0.32 * 100 = 32
```

Comment: thanks for reply! i have another question, it different from extracting color using MMCQ algorithm from RGB model? (like color-thief and vibrant.js library above)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Kleur.js](https://github.com/miri-san-so/Kleur) you can use to get images but remember that it gives random color palette every time. But the dominant color will remain the same in every color pallete

```
// Create the Kleur Object
Kleur = new Kleur();

// Set the image link to get the palette from
imageObj = Kleur.init(imgLink);

// Wait for the image to load
imageObj.onload = function(e) {

    // get the color array from the image
    let colorArr = Kleur.getPixelArray(imageObj);

    // pass the array to generate the color array
    let array_of_pixels = Kleur.generateColorArray(colorArr);

    // you can get the dominant color from the image
    const dominant = Kleur.getDominant(array_of_pixels);

    // log the light colors and the dominant color
    console.log(light, dominant)
}
```

if you want to see an example for using this code visit the [codepen](https://codepen.io/mirisama/pen/YzXjxew)

And if you want all the dominant colors which I think is the colors with the most pixels you can access the array_of_pixels, so you could do

```
// for first five dominant color
for(let x = 0; x < 5; x++){
    console.log(array_of_pixels[x].hsv);
}

// for the dominant colors hsv value
console.log(dominant.hsv)
```

this will log the hsv values for the five most dominant color in the image(usually the dominant colors are really similar so look out for that)

Kleur js returns colors in various color space

- RGB
- HEX
- HSV
- XYZ
- LAB
- LCH

it also returns count which is the number of pixels that have the color